# Save chat history from watson conversation service to Cloudant NoSQL DB

Tags: node.js, cloudant, chatbot, watson-conversation

Firstly,When I am starting the conversation,I am asking the user for their email address.
The application is deployed in bluemix in nodejs
 After the conversation is completed,I want the chat history to be emailed to the given email address.Is it possible? If it is possible, can I save the chat history in the JSON format in Cloudant NoSQL DB ?
 Is there any tutorials on how to go about with this?

Comment: Your question is a but too broad to answer fully.  What is the output from the watson conversation service? How are you interacting with the service, from a bluemix nodejs, java, something else app?  For the last question, have you seen https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/cloudant/?

Comment: The output from the service is like any other chat bot service where based on intents a selected response is given .I am using node.js application deployed in bluemix.Yeah I have checked out that documentation,but that doesnot show how to integrate to a conversation service from a nodejs app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that you will find documentation for your entire use case, However, there are a few sources of information available to you.

- There is a conversation service demo app written in nodejs https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple. In particular, take a look at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js for the conversation code.
- There is a nodejs library for Cloudant https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant. In that link you will find examples of how to connect to Cloudant and persist data.
- For emailing you will probably need to subscribe to a service like [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/sendgrid-api/).  In that link you will find documentation for sending emails using nodejs.

As a developer, you will need to integrate the APIs for watson conversation, cloudant and sendgrid in your nodejs application.

Comment: Adding to that,Watson conversation service has the option to "improve" where all the conversation transcripts are stored.